# Whirlpool tub Wiring circuit

Tags: electrical

Ran in to a whirlpool tub with a heater on 14.2 wire hooked up on a 20 amp breaker that’s all that’s on the line with a gfi plug any problems

Comment: Is this a dedicated circuit for the hot tub or is the hot tub plugged into an outside receptacle which is on a circuit with other loads?

Answer (score 3):

14 Gauge wire on a 20Amp breaker is a clear code violation if you are in the USA, at least. It needs to be replaced with 12 Gauge minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there something in the code about power for electric motors having different requirements for gauge of wire and breaker size?

For example, I believe on this site there have been questions about wiring for water pumps and a/c compressors where #12 wire is allowed with a 30-A breaker or #10 wire with a 40-A breaker.

http://www.ecmweb.com/code-basics/motors-and-nec

> The small conductor rule contained in 240.4(D), which limits 15A
>   protection for 14 AWG, doesn’t apply to motor circuit protection. See
>   240.4(D) and 240.4(G).

In the case of this hot tub is the #14 wire supplying both resistance heat and a motor for pumping?

Comment: A whirlpool wouldn't fall under Art. 430 as it's a nameplated appliance, not a bare motor used directly

Comment: Presumably the appliance would have a plate specifying the breaker size and type, but would it also specify the conductor required?

Comment: It wouldn't be on the nameplate unless it was an AC/R appliance falling under Art. 440 provisions